# Does .ebextensions or requirements.txt run first in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

the `.config` file in `.ebextensions` or `requirements.txt` runs first?

I want to install `psycopg2` present in `requirements.txt` for that, I need to install `postgresql-devel`, `python-devel` packages installed first.

When I create my config settings like

**requirements.txt**

```
psycopg2
```

**.ebextensions/mysite.config**

```
packages:
  yum:
    gcc: []
    python-devel: []
    postgresql-devel: []
```

1. From the logs, I observed that, requirements.txt executed first, thus raising errors as prerequisites are not installed.
2. yum is raising `postgresql-devel` is not found in packages.

How do I fix these? Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Hi Surya, have you found an answer for your question?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error and got it to work specifying a version

```
packages:
  yum:
    libxslt-devel: ''
    postgresql93-devel: []
```